# Can't show bibliography, citations undefined

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, undefined

I'm trying to add a bibliography, using `biblatex`, but when I compile with texmaker I just get many warnings saying all the citations are undefined.

Briefly, here is how my project is structured:

Dissertate.cls

```
...
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
...
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{ 
    \bibpage
}
...
\newcommand{\bibpage}{  
    ...   
    \printbibliography
}
```

references.bib

```
@inbook{Wilson001,
   author    = {Wilson J.},
   title     = {Some title},
   ...
}
```

dissertation.tex

```
\documentclass{Dissertate}
\begin{document}
...
\include{mainmatter/chapters/chapter1}

\backmatter
...
\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex

```
\chapter{First Chapter}
Here I'm going to add a citation \cite{Wilson001}. ...
```

The warning I get is, for example: `Citation 'Wilson001' on page 1 undefined`. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you run biber?

Comment: Thank you! Actually I'm a beginner, I didn't run biber... How can I do it?

Comment: I do not know texmaker, so I can not tell you how to configurate it. There is a question about that theme here on the page, if I can find it, I can post a link to it ...

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document, so that the full compilation sequence becomes LaTeX, Biber; LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains why, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 helps you configure your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Any news here? Did you go through the instructions in the linked question to make sure your editor runs Biber and not BibTeX for you? If so, did it work? If not, can you explain why the linked answers were inadequate? If you can now run Biber and still don't get the desired outcome, please show us the `.blg` file. If there is no new development here in due time I will vote to close this question as duplicate of the "configure your editor for Biber" question.